# Tess4j exeption

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь реализовать пример использования Tess4j, столкнулся вот с таким исключением:

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/oleg/workspace/ocr/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/oleg/workspace/ocr/lib/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:436)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:291)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
at ocr.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:19)
Error opening data file ./tessdata/ru.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'ru'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

Работаю на Windows-x64, задал системную переменную: TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Users\oleg\workspace\ocr\tessdata. Структура проекта на скрине во вложении [image: Скрин проекта].

Помогите победить ошибку, пожалуйста!

Comment: Поменял переменную окружения:
TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Users\oleg\workspace\ocr\
Не помогло.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось проще:
1. переменная TESSDATA_PREFIX должна указывать на каталог, в котором лежит tessdata.
2. в каталоге tessdata должны лежать данные для русского языка, если документ на русском.
3. самое важное - файл rus.traineddata скачанный с github нужно переименовать в ru.traineddata.

Только после этого заработает.